# Query timed out error while publishing the component

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

When I trying to publish a Component I am getting **query timed out error**.

The component is not so large. The Component publish fails at

> Waiting for deployment-->resolving-->Failed

I tried increasing the timeouts in SDL Tridion Configuration Manager but it did not work.

There are no corresponding logs in event viewer.

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: I can't understand which query would be timing out... could it be something in the template itself? Do you get this error when previewing?

Comment: Try enabling the publisher log in the Snap-in.  It may provide additional info.

Comment: Can you try publishing the same component with a different component template, and a different component with the original component template?

Comment: @NunoLinhares. The preview works fine. But publishing fails.

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov.. Thanks for the hint. I enabled it. But also nothing was logged with respect to this. I restarted IIS, COM+, and Services too.

Comment: @NVanderEnde. I tried publishing the other components in the current publication using the same CT, it was failed. Publish is successful when publishing some other component in another publication using same CT.

Comment: Are the publications using the same publication target settings?

Comment: @NVanderEnde. No the target are different.

Comment: Are they using different deployers, even?

Comment: @NVanderEnde. They are published to two different machines.

Comment: Would it be possible to post relevant CT code? There's probably something in there which times out, like doing heavy operations or unwittingly creating an infinite loop..

Answer (score 4):

Without a specific error message, it's difficult to diagnose this problem properly; however, if it's failing while resolving then it's not likely to be an issue with the CT but, if you have a lot of Component Links, a possible culprit is an exponential tree of dependencies causing a timeout when resolving items to publish (off the top of my head I think the stored procedure in question is called something along the lines of EDA_GETPUBLISHITEMS). You can test for this by choosing "Show Items to Publish" on the Publish dialog and seeing how long it takes to resolve all of the Component Links.

We've encountered this in a production environment in the past and after trying various other things (service packs, configuration, database maintenance), we ended up implementing an event handler to subscribe to the `ComponentPublishPre` event and override Component Link resolution so dependencies (except Multimedia Components) aren't published.

```
/// <summary>
/// Disable link resolution for component publishing
/// </summary>
public void OverrideLinkResolution(Component component, PublishEventArgs args,
                                   EventPhases phase)
{
    var targets = args.Targets.Cast<TargetType>().ToArray();
    args.PublishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeComponentLinks = false;

    // If this component uses any multimedia components then publish them too
    foreach (var item in component.GetUsedItems())
    {
        var relatedComponent = item as Component;
        if (relatedComponent != null
            && relatedComponent.ComponentType == ComponentType.Multimedia)
        {
            item.Publish(targets, true, false);
        }
    }
}
```

This has the drawback that content editors will have to publish dependencies manually in order to get Component Links (particularly in Rich Text fields) to work, though in our case this wasn't undesirable as there was such a rich network of links that publishing any dynamic Component Presentation was likely to take all sorts of unready content with it.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue, try running "sp_updatestats" for each database and it would fix the issue. I have just fixed this issue.